How to deal with the situation when I'm being ghosted by potential employer even after having a discussion with the discipline head?
I was referred for a job position by a friend working in an organisation. Thier discipline head found me suitable for the role. He had expressed that to my friend. Then he called me over phone to have an informal discussion. After the discussion he said he was interested to conduct a formal interview. Next day, recruitment team calls me and asks their usual questions such as notice period, current salary, salary expectations, location preference, availablility for interview, etc. (All of these were already discussed during informal discussion).
Now a week after this, they hadn't contacted me for the interview confirmation.
The recruiter answered my followup phone call. She said they were busy with upcoming walk-in interviews and asked me to call after 3 days. Now after 3 days, I'm being ghosted since they are not answering my phone calls.
Should I check with that discipline head to see what went wrong?
I have 10+ years experience and ghosting for such positions don't seem appropriate to me.

It is possible that they have filled the position in the meantime. Personally, I would be interviewing elsewhere until they come back with something more solid.

Like it or not, ghosting is standard practice. They could be busy, they may have a more promising candidate to work on or they already have mode. Ignore it. If something comes from it: great. But don't rely on it and keep looking elsewhere until you have a written offer in hand. Personally I blacklist employers that ghost me and the list has become depressingly long. A simple "thanks, but no thanks" is all it takes but employers who value candidates so little that they can't be bothered are not my choice.

How long/often after "3 days" did you try to reach them? Your question reads like you were in perfect contact with them and then you assume "ghosting" when they didn't pick up the phone the minute you called... how often did you try to reach them?

Last week was thanksgiving, warrants a bit of slack. Though I would definitely keep on interviewing, you don't have a job until you have signed a contract.

Today, a one minute phone call “sorry ,  but we decided not to hire you because…” is too much ho ask for.

What continent, region, or country is this company based in? Specifically, is it a U.S. company (no matter where the job actually is)?

Ghosting is the new norm. Welcome to the job market.

We cannot know what is going on in the company. Maybe there is a small disorganization, lack of communication, or something else.
However, my personal experience (not excessively rich) is that this kind of behavior is a red flag (possibly small).
This is why my advice is like this: if it is not very important that you get employed at this company, keep searching. In this way, you will have a backup in case that something unhappy happens.
If they will ask "But why?", you will just say simply "While I waited for feedback from you, I received a good offer from another company."
Business is business.

Even if it is very important that you get employed at this company, continue searching until someone commits to hiring you, in writing, with an actual contract and start date. Short of that, you have no meaningful promise that you will be hired. Even after that, they can change their mind, but will be far less likely to.

Relevant because of recent holidays, assuming usa based job.
For a lot of great companies to work at, thanksgiving week is not a good week to get a hold of them. People are out of office visiting family, eating too much turkey, ham, mashed potatoes, etc... And are not available to call back/respond, because they don't work while out on vacation.
Yes, the office worker probably should have said 3-4 days after thanksgiving week instead of the date they gave. But assume this was a mistake on HRs part, and try contacting them at the end of this week, once they have caught up from a weeklong holiday.

So the question becomes if they are treating you like this now, why would you want to work for them?  All of this says far more about them, then it does about you.
They confirmed you are suitable for a role, but then didn't hire you?  If this was a person a friend was trying to date, you would advise them to move on to someone else.  Same thing here, you are being gaslighted.
Find a different job or continue to work at your current employer.
I suspect that they are trying to find someone cheaper than you that can do the job adequately.  That is just a guess, and it could be many reasons for such poor treatment.  Be assured that the poor treatment will continue after they find someone(s) to fill the role(s).

If you have not been to an interview or had one scheduled, then I wouldn't over-analyze this. There's usually a mutual lack of empathy in these situations, where one party doesn't really understand what the other is going through.
Candidates are often in a position where they really need a job and so every application where the employer is responsive or showing interest becomes a really big deal to them personally. But to the employer they are just one of many applying for this job. Employers sometimes also fail to grasp that candidates will often be applying to multiple jobs, so there may be a limited time window when the candidate is still available.
Whereas the employer is often in a position where they have to juggle some 50 to 100 candidates in a timely manner. Quite often in addition to doing their regular job, where various emergencies might pop up. In fact the reason why they are so busy in the first place is quite likely the reason they are looking to hire more staff. Now imagine if a portion of those 100 candidates start to breathe down their neck in the middle of all that...
Also, particularly in smaller organizations and start-ups, the recruiter might not be particularly experienced in the process of recruiting in itself.
It is a nice and decent thing to reach out to all rejected candidates with a simple "sorry but we have chosen to move forward with other candidates". This is far from the norm though, sadly. Most often it is not intentional "ghosting" but just general neglect or lack of time. If you don't get a reply, don't read too much into it, just move on.
If you have also spoken with them on the phone, well it's poor manners not to get back to you, but again don't read too much into it. And in particular don't waste energy fuming over not getting that particular job.
If you have been to an interview on the other hand, they really do need to get in touch with you and inform you of their decision going forward. Not reaching out to someone you had on an interview would be very poor form and that definitely says something bad about the company.

Risk versus reward. You have nothing to lose by being persistent BUT POLITE.
If US based (as other answers pointed out), the employer might be behind due to the holiday.
It can't hurt to have your name at the top of the pile while they are clearing their desk. If they are overwhelmed, let them think of you as the quick solution to the hiring need.
If they are ghosting you, then it doesn't matter anyway.
